# What does Boost Wave not do?

Tags: c++, c, boost, c-preprocessor

Boost Wave provides a reusable C preprocessor. It's easy to obtain from the documentation the (extensive) list of the things it does do, standards it supports, features it includes etc.

What does it *not* do? Does it support all the nonstandard extensions of GCC and Microsoft C++? Or the various vendor compilers used for embedded systems? How does it fare on the various syntaxes for in-line assembly, or deprecated code from oddball legacy systems? Has anyone tried it on e.g. the full Linux kernel sources or Windows header sets?

Comment: There are predefined macro - http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/wave/doc/predefined_macros.html. and you can define macro, by context::add_macro_definition http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/wave/doc/class_reference_context.html, you can also setup wave library for work with one of standards (control extended options)

Comment: "How does it fare on the various syntaxes for in-line assembly" - I can't imagine they'd make any unusual demands of the preprocessor... do you have an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, got it compiled and ran a couple of experiments myself. Thus far it appears to not support this GCC extension:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Directives-Within-Macro-Arguments.html#Directives-Within-Macro-Arguments

and also barfs on the Microsoft header file C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\vc\include\xkeycheck.h containing the following construct:

```
#if defined(auto)   /* check C keywords */  \
|| defined(break) \
...
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to find out if it supports your favorite extension is to just, you know, **try it**. Is probably even *way* faster to ask here and wait for enough comments/answers to accumulate to be able to conclude something. Or check the documentation, if it doesn't talk about GCC/MSC extensions at all, it probably just doesn't know of them.